# Erlang: does sys:get_status/1 interfere with timeout?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Say I have a gen_server process, P, which contains codes like this

```
handle_call(get_a, _From, #state{a = 1}=S) ->
    Reply = S#state.a,
    {reply, Reply, S, T=1000000};
```

If I do `gen_server:call(P, get_a)`, then I would get a reply, namely `1`, and if no message was sent to P in `T` after the gen call, then a timeout will occur.

If I do a `sys:get_status(P)` immediately after the gen call, would this cancel the timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [`sys:get_status/1,2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#get_status-1) on your `gen_server` process does not cancel the timeout. And just for completeness, note that this is true whether or not your `gen_server` implements the optional [`format_status/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:format_status-2) callback.